# Magento Wrong Attribute Group ID after installing stockinthechannel extension

Tags: php, magento

I am facing a weird error when installing stockinthechannel extension which linked here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sell-ingram-micro-techdata-100-other-suppliers-products.html

the error is shown below:

---

Mage_Eav_Exception Object
(
    [_messages:protected] => Array
        (
        )

```
[message:protected] => Wrong attribute group ID
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 0
[file:protected] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/Mage.php
[line:protected] => 581
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php
                [line] => 522
                [function] => exception
                [class] => Mage
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Mage_Eav
                        [1] => Wrong attribute group ID
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [file] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php
                [line] => 1034
                [function] => getAttributeGroupId
                [class] => Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 4
                        [1] => 17067
                        [2] => General
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [file] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php
                [line] => 680
                [function] => addAttributeToSet
                [class] => Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 4
                        [1] => 17067
                        [2] => General
                        [3] => ean
                        [4] => 
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [file] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 106
                [function] => addAttribute
                [class] => Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => catalog_product
                        [1] => ean
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [label] => EAN
                                [type] => varchar
                                [input] => text
                                [backend] => eav/entity_attribute_backend_array
                                [frontend] => 
                                [source] => 
                                [global] => 1
                                [visible] => 1
                                [required] => 
                                [user_defined] => 
                                [searchable] => 
                                [filterable] => 
                                [comparable] => 
                                [visible_on_front] => 1
                                [visible_in_advanced_search] => 
                                [unique] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [file] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/local/Bintime/Sinchimport/sql/sinchimport_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php
                [line] => 32
                [function] => addAttribute
                [class] => Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => catalog_product
                        [1] => ean
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [label] => EAN
                                [type] => varchar
                                [input] => text
                                [backend] => eav/entity_attribute_backend_array
                                [frontend] => 
                                [source] => 
                                [global] => 1
                                [visible] => 1
                                [required] => 
                                [user_defined] => 
                                [searchable] => 
                                [filterable] => 
                                [comparable] => 
                                [visible_on_front] => 1
                                [visible_in_advanced_search] => 
                                [unique] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [file] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 624
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/local/Bintime/Sinchimport/sql/sinchimport_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php
                    )

                [function] => include
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [file] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 437
                [function] => _modifyResourceDb
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => upgrade
                        [1] => 0.1.0
                        [2] => 3.0.4
                    )

            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [file] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 320
                [function] => _upgradeResourceDb
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0.1.0
                        [1] => 3.0.4
                    )

            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [file] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                [line] => 235
                [function] => applyUpdates
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [file] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                [line] => 417
                [function] => applyAllUpdates
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [file] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                [line] => 343
                [function] => _initModules
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [file] => [hide url for security]/public_html/app/Mage.php
                [line] => 685
                [function] => run
                [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [scope_code] => 
                                [scope_type] => store
                                [options] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [file] => [hide url for security]/public_html/index.php
                [line] => 87
                [function] => run
                [class] => Mage
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => store
                    )

            )

    )

[previous:Exception:private] =>
```

)
 Magento Commerce
There has been an error processing your request
Error in file: "[hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/local/Bintime/Sinchimport/sql/sinchimport_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php" - Wrong attribute group ID

Trace:

```
#0 [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.1.0', '3.0.4')
#2 [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('0.1.0', '3.0.4')
#3 [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 [hide url for security]/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 [hide url for security]/public_html/app/Mage.php(685): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 [hide url for security]/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Error log record number: 1056069990613

---

can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **Magento Connect Manager->Settings Tab** 
and set these settings as directed:

```
Magento Connect Channel Protocol: http 
Preferred State: stable 
Use custom permissions: Yes 
Folders: 755 
Files:755 
Deployment Type: Localfilesystem
```